# "Require not ip" .htaccess doesn't work in a single ip

Tags: apache-2.4, ip, .htaccess, ubuntu-14.04, block

I am having trouble with blocking an IP in .htaccess

I've put

```
Require not ip 192.168.20.218
```

It works, but it blocks the entire network instead of blocking a single IP.

Can somebody solve this issue?

I am running on Apache 2.4 using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

**UPDATE:** scenario is like this, I am using IP `192.168.20.218` on my computer, I am trying to do a test to block this IP address, I tried:

```
<RequireAll> 
Require all granted 
Require not ip 192.168.20.218 
</RequireAll>
```

Which is supposed to block my access, but instead it's still allowing me to access the page. If I take out the `Require all granted` it blocks the entire network.

Comment: Regarding your update... "Something" is not quite right here!? I would say the most probable cause of this failing (and still allowing access) is that the IP you're "blocking" is not the IP that your web server sees when you access your site. (?) If you take out `Require all granted` it will indeed block the "entire network" - in fact, it will block _everything_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a *negated* directive by itself in order to authorize access. As noted in [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require):

> The result of the `Require` directive may be negated through the use of the `not` option. As with the other negated authorization directive `<RequireNone>`, **when the `Require` directive is negated it can only fail or return a neutral result, and therefore may never independently authorize a request**.

You would need to do something like the following instead:

```
<RequireAll>
Require all granted
Require not ip 192.168.20.218
</RequireAll>
```

So, you allow everyone and exclude a particular IP address.

The `<RequireAll>` container, as its name suggests, requires that all contained directives must be satisfied.

Comment: even this won't work <RequireAll>
Require all granted
Require not ip 192.168.20.218
</RequireAll>

Comment: This doesn't work either, instead this "Require all granted" allows to access all ip including the said ip address <192.168.20.218> even i put "Require not ip"

Comment: You need the `<RequireAll>` wrapper. What does it do? Block _everyone_ again? Is this in the `.htaccess` file in the document root of your site? Any other directives? All caches cleared?

Comment: I already did the same <RequireAll>
Require all granted
Require not ip 192.168.20.218
</RequireAll> - still this one won't work . do i need to do something in the apache.conf ? or the site-enabled/000-default.conf?

Comment: "What does it do?" / In what way does it not work? Your question implies that `.htaccess` files are enabled and mod_authz_core is enabled (it should be as it's compiled into a default Apache build) - otherwise your initial directive wouldn't have blocked access. (However, if you access to the server config then you probably shouldn't be using `.htaccess`.)

Comment: MrWhite - scenario is like this, I am using IP 192.168.20.218 in my computer, I am trying to do a test to block ip address, I tried the code <RequireAll>
Require all granted
Require not ip 192.168.20.218
</RequireAll>, and still it allows me to access the page. if I take out the "Require all granted" it blocks the entire network.

Comment: the document root is /var/www/html the htaccess is located at the folder /var/www/html/folder, there is no other directives , no caches activate mod_file_cache is disable>>>>>Is this in the .htaccess file in the document root of your site? Any other directives? All caches cleared? – MrWhite 1 hour ago

Comment: And the URL you are requesting includes `/folder`?

Comment: I guess I know what is the problem. I cannot use the "Require not ip"  when i check the ip address while browsing my application, it comes from one ip address "192.168.10.1" which is the gateway. it doesn't come from a unique ip address

Comment: That would imply your application is on a different network? `192.168.x.x` are all internal IP addresses. If your application is on "the public internet" (for example) then your application will only see the _external_ (public) IP address of your gateway when any machine on the LAN accesses your application. (`192.168.10.1` is the LAN side of your gateway, not the external IP address.)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I forgot I had an nginx reverse proxy in place. The IP coming into apache was the reverse proxy IP from nginx. Instead, I had to set a custom header in the reverse proxy containing the true IP, and then check this header in .htaccess instead of checking the ip.